# Authentication + Persistant login with JWT and refresh token

Tags: authentication, jwt, redux-toolkit

Stack: React, tRPC, Redux Toolkit

So I'm trying to build out my auth in a way that's somewhat secure and can handle persistent logins. The best approach I've found so far is to have a short-lived JWT that authenticates the user, and then a refresh token with a key saved on the DB that allows new short-lived JWTs to be generated. The short lived token would be stored in my Redux store, while the refresh token would be saved as a cookie so it can be used to log in the user when they refresh the page.

So my first question is, is this in general a good way to approach this problem? I see conflicting answers sometimes.

The second problem I'm facing is that if I want to use a refresh token, I'm going to have to check and see if the JWT is not expired before each API call, and if it is, hit the /refresh endpoint and use the new JWT. However, with my current stack, I'm not sure how to do this in away that doesn't involve a lot of copy and paste code.

The only solutions I've been able to think of so far are:

1. Just include both JWT and refresh token in every API call. Always send back either the same JWT or a new JWT. If the refresh token is expired, send back a 401.
2. Do something to so that before every thunk is dispatched, check the JWT/refresh token and hit /refresh if needed before dispatching.

I'm sure there's a better way to handle this though. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need the short-lived JWT in the first place? Maybe all you need is a good-old cookie-based session. In fact, what you describe with how the refresh token would be used + the first proposed solution, is pretty much how you would use a session. Unless there is a real need for short-lived JWTs as access tokens, I would get rid of them.

If you decide to stick to access and refresh tokens, then what you describe in solution 2 is not enough. You always need a way of intercepting a 401 response from the API, which indicates that the access token is expired. You should then refresh the access token and call the API again. If the refresh fails with 401, then you know that the refresh token is expired. The expiration check needs to be done on the backend because only there you are sure of the clock settings. Clients can have their clocks skewed which makes verifying expiration time on the client side useless.